# UINavigation Controller pops title but not controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is the setup: I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in it.  When one of the cells is touched, an action sheet appears offering the option to choose a photo from your library or take a new photo.  In either case, I display a `UIImagePickerController` like so:

in my interface declaration

```
UIImagePickerController* imageController;
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
imageController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imageController.delegate = self;
imageController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

in my action sheet delegate method

```
if(buttonIndex == 2)
    return;

UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

if(buttonIndex == 1)
    sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

imageController.sourceType = sourceType;

[self presentModalViewController:imageController animated:YES];
```

That works fine, and the image picker gets displayed.  From this point on however the navigation controller doesn't seem to work properly.  I can call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and the title in the navigation bar will change with the standard pop animation, but the controller itself will not disappear.  This only happens after the image picker controller has been displayed.  I can cancel the action sheet before displaying the controller and there isn't any problem at all.

I have included a link to a short video since this app is already live - this is just a re-build.

http://screencast.com/t/qBolp2v3iCyR

I have tried displaying the modal from the navigation controller and the tab bar controller - same result.  I have tried the alternative display method using this call:

```
[self presentViewController:imageController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

I have verified that my navigation controller is not nil, and that the appropriate controllers are on the stack.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your code where you are pushing viewcontroller.May be problem is there

Comment: Nothing strange when I push the controller on the stack.  I make a call to [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueName" sender:self].  My prepareForSegue method isn't complicated and just sets the values on the destination controller.

Comment: I also just tried commenting everything in the prepareForSegue method out and it is still happening.

Comment: **UPDATE** If I switch between tabs after reaching the top of the navigation stack I can get the screen to refresh and the app continues as normal.  Maybe something in the navigation controller is getting messed up and the 'viewWillAppear' or 'viewWillDisappear' isn't getting called?  See demo video here: http://screencast.com/t/zKxCwgoz4

Comment: **SOLUTION** Found a solution that is a complete and total hack - While the image picker is being dismissed I switch the selected tab of my tab bar controller and then back again.  This has the effect of causing the navigation controller to be reset in some manner.  I know - it's a hack and I still don't know exactly what is going on, but it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this,
if you display viewController with

```
[self presentModalViewController:imageController animated:YES];
```

your must dismissView with

```
[imageController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

because popViewController will use when display view with pushViewController

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss a controller added using `presentModalViewController:animated:`, you should use

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: I just tried this and I still have the same problem.  Thanks though.